# How to write a for loop to read multiple csv files into R and subset the data to make clean dataframes for ggplots?

Tags: r, loops, subset, gsub, assign

I am trying to read multiple csvs into R and then subset those csvs by removing columns I don't need using the 'subset' function.  i am trying to setup a for loop in r that I can add functions or calculation to a list of csvs in order to produce dataframes for ggplots or stat analysis later. (I currently have tidyverse, dplyr, and ggplot2 installed). Right now I just want to subset the csvs and then create a dataframe from the subsetted data.

I used a for loop to successfully read multiple csvs into separate dataframes by setting a working directory, creating a list of csvs, then reading them into dataframes.  This currently outputs a dataframe for each csv named after the original filename:

```
filenames <- gsub("\\.csv$","", list.files(pattern="\\.csv$"))


for(i in filenames){
     assign(i, read.csv(paste(i, ".csv", sep="")))}
```

Then I realized I wanted to subset these data before putting them into the dataframes in order to avoid some repetitive code later; however, I am getting an error each time I tried to add a subset function to the for loop.  This is what I currently have:

```
for(i in filenames){
  read.csv(i)
  subset(i, select = c("names", "of columns", "I want"))
  assign(i, read.csv(paste(i, ".csv", sep="")))
}
```

I receive a "no such file or directory error". I'm sure I'm missing something obvious since my R foundation is poor, but any help or advice to make this work would be appreciated.  The subset function has worked for me in the past but I had to write out a new line for each dataframe and would like to avoid that by using a list and for loop or some other method.

Thank you

Comment: Using `assign` isn't a great idea. See list alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once. But here the variable `i` is just the file name. You need to save the result of `read.csv` somewhere or pass that directly to subset. But the `lapply` list strategy is generally going to be easier to work with in the long run.

Comment: Thank you I will try that out and get back to you

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, all csv files do have the same structure, i.e., same number and names of columns. Therefore, the suggestion by [MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54873498/how-to-write-a-for-loop-to-read-multiple-csv-files-into-r-and-subset-the-data-to?rq=1#comment96517039_54873498) and [OP's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54875842/3817004) can be improved in several ways:

1. The `read.csv()` function reads all columns. Therefore, a separate subsetting step is required to keep only the wanted columns. The `fread()` function from the `data.table` package has a `select` parameter to *read* only the wanted columns from file.
2. `rbindlist()` is an abbreviation of `do.call(rbind, ...)` but has an additional parameter `idcol`. This will create an additional column which identifies the origin of each row.

#### Create list of data frames

```
lapply(list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$"), data.table::fread, 
       select = c("names.of", "columns", "I.want"))
```

> ```
> [[1]]
>    names.of columns I.want
> 1:        1       2      3
>
> [[2]]
>    names.of columns I.want
> 1:       21      22     23
> ```

Note that only selected columns are read from files.

#### Create one large dataframe

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)   # piping used here to improve readability
lapply(list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$"), fread, select = c("names.of", "columns", "I.want")) %>% 
  rbindlist(idcol = TRUE)
```

> ```
>    .id names.of columns I.want
> 1:   1        1       2      3
> 2:   2       21      22     23
> 3:   2       31      32     33
> ```

Note that the `.id` column gives the sequence number of list elements.

#### Create one large dataframe with originating file names

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
filenames = list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")
lapply(filenames, fread, select = c("names.of", "columns", "I.want")) %>% 
  set_names(filenames) %>% 
  rbindlist(idcol = "origin")
```

> ```
>       origin names.of columns I.want
> 1: test1.csv        1       2      3
> 2: test2.csv       21      22     23
> 3: test2.csv       31      32     33
> ```

Here, `set_names()` from the `magrittr` package is used to name the list elements.
Then, `rbindlist()` uses the names of the list elements for the id column.

#### Sample data

If have created two files.

`test1.csv` contains one row and four columns:

> ```
> "names.of", "columns", "I.want", "useless.column"
> 1, 2, 3, 4
> ```

`test2.csv` contains two rows and five columns:

> ```
> "names.of", "columns", "I.want", "useless.column", "another.useless.column"
> 21, 22, 23, 24, 25
> 31, 32, 33, 34, 35
> ```

Note that I have modified the column names to ensure that they are syntactically valid variable names.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using @MrFlick suggestion and circumvented for loops entirely using lapply and combining all files in one dataframe and subsetting from there. final result below:

```
filenames = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
filenames

myfiles = do.call(rbind, lapply(filenames, function(x) read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))

myfiles


myfiles.subset = subset(myfiles, select = c("names of", "columns", "I want")
```