# How to combine path and variable in readr read_csv (list.files for loop)?

Tags: r, readr

I need to mass-import some data for my R project. Following some guide, I wrote a simple for loop which goes like that:

```
for (for_variable in list.files(path = "./data", pattern = ".csv$")) {
  temp <- read_csv(for_variable)
  # Some data wranglig
  database <- rbind(database, temp)
  rm(temp)
  }
```

The problem is that my data is in the data folder in my working directory, as I've specified in `list.files(path = "./data")`. The problem is that I can't use `read_csv(for_variable)` because I get an error:

```
'file_name.csv' does not exist in current working directory
```

And if I try to specify the path in `read_csv`, it doesn't understand what 'for_variable' is, it tries to find literal 'for_variable' file in the data folder. So how can I combine path and variable name in `read_csv`? Or is there any other way of solving the problem?

Comment: (1) Use `list.files(..., full.names=TRUE)`, as EJJ suggested. (2) Do not iteratively build data, it is horribly inefficient, create a `list` of frames and then do one call of `database <- do.call(rbind, list_of_frames)`. For the former, see [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)'s chapter 2 on *Growing objects*; for the latter, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227.

Comment: @r2evans I'd love not to use the loop but I don't know how to do the wrangling if I don't. I want to slice, select and mutate my temporary data before binding it because the files I got are quite messy. Luckily they're all messy in the same way so I can clean them all with:
`temp %<>% slice(4:11) %>% select(form_2.index, form_2.response) %>% mutate(plec = as.character(temp[1,4]), wiek = as.double(temp[2,4]), uczestnik = as.character(temp[1,13]), warunek = as.character(temp[1,16]), data = ymd_hm(temp[1,15]))`
How do I do it without the loop?

Comment: I've made a question out of it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67252097/how-to-address-specific-cell-in-lapply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54873498/how-to-write-a-for-loop-to-read-multiple-csv-files-into-r-and-subset-the-data-to) as it is helpful for importing multiple csv files.

But to help with your specific question, your error is likely caused becauseo you need to pass the **full** path name for the files you want to import and that can be specified by using the `full.names = TRUE` argument in `list.files()`. Passing just the file name contained in `for_variable` to `read_csv` won't work.

```
list.files(path = "./data", full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".csv$")
```