# How to address specific cell in lapply?

Tags: r, lapply

I want to "upgrade" my code by replacing mass-import using for loop with lapply function. After using `lapply(list.files(), read.csv)` I've got a list of dataframes. The problem is, the data is a bit messy and some things (like participant's sex) are mentioned only once, in one specific cell. It wasn't a problem when I used a for loop, as I could just refer to a specific cell. When I used:

```
for (x in list.files()) {
temp <- read.csv(x)
temp %>% slice(4:11) %>% select(form_2.index, form_2.response) %>% mutate(sex = temp[1,4])
#temp[1,4] is the one cell where the participant's sex is mentioned
database <- rbind(datadase, temp)
```

each temp variable looked like this:

```
  form_2.index form_2.response sex$form.response
         <dbl> <chr>           <chr>             
1            1 yes             male         
2            2 no              male         
3            3 no              male         
4            4 yes             male         
5            5 yes             male         
6            6 yes             male         
7            7 no              male         
8            8 no              male
```

That's what I want. But how can I refer to a certain cell when using lapply? The following code doesn't work, as the temp variable is now a list:

```
temp <- lapply(list.files(), read_csv())
temp %>% lapply(slice, 4:11) %>% lapply(select, form_2.index, form_2.response) %>% lapply(mutate, plec = temp[1,4])
```

The `slice` and `select` functions work all right, the problem lies in the `mutate` part. Given it's a list, I need to point to a certain element of the list, not only column and row, but how can I do that? After all, I want it to be done in each element. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do :

```
library(dplyr)

temp <- lapply(list.files(), function(x) {
  tmp <- readr::read_csv(x)
  tmp %>%
    slice(4:11) %>% 
    select(form_2.index, form_2.response) %>% 
    mutate(sex = tmp[1,4])
})
```

Comment: That's clever, thank you. Would you be able to explain why the outcome is the tmp variable and I don't need to do anything like `return(tmp)` or something like that; telling the function what it should return?

Comment: You can do but it is not necessary. If you don't have an explicit `return` in the function it by default returns whatever is present at the last line.